# Monitor with adjustable height for home office?

Tags: monitors

I am looking for a new external monitor to connect to various laptops. My use case here is home office, not gaming.

Requirements:

- 27 to 32 inch (bigger is better).
- Adjustable height for ergonomical reasons.
- Audio jack so I can connect headphones.
- Full HD.

Bonuses:

- Built in speakers.
- Built in USB-hub.
- Built in webcam.
- Resolutions above full HD.

Not important:

- Fancy refreash rates, response times or ultra pro gaming features.

I have been browsing through the websites of major Swedish reatilers, without finding a single monitor fulfilling the requirements. The adjustable height seems to be the major problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Dell U2417H and love it.  It has the swivel feature so you can use it in either landscape or portrait, has a USB 3.0 hub (4 3.0 outputs), has a headphone jack, can be adjusted up and down, and the image quality is fantastic.  I would highly recommend it.  I found a 27" QHD model [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JGSPQV2).

Answer (score 0):

AOC has some models that fulfill all the requirements, and the bonuses except the webcam. They can be found [here](https://eu.aoc.com/se/monitors/professional-solutions/28-inch/27-inch/32-inch/usb-hub/speakers). The [AOC Q27P2Q](https://eu.aoc.com/se/monitors/q27p2q) is one example.